# Unable to update database to match the current model. Failing only on self hosting project

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, self-hosting

The following code:

```
Database.SetInitializer
(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Db, Migrations.Configuration>(true));
using (var C = new Db())
{
   Console.WriteLine(C.Usuarios.Count());
}
```

Works on a console test project but on the other console with self-hosting it fails with the `Unable to update database to match the current model...` migration error

Obviously the migrations are up to date since the other project runs fine and they both do the same configuration since the database model and the migration configuration are on a separated library

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the problem to the `Newtonsoft.Json` library.

The package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` depends on the version 6.0.4 of this library which seems to have conflicts with Entity Framework.

Just upgrading the `Newtonsoft.Json` with `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json` solves the problem